# Angular Put request with body example

Tags: angular

URL FOR PUT request is **http://localhost:8080/user/userId/update**

**user** is a body with JSON data and **userId** is string.**Update** is a method.

where 
user={
"name":"value",
"age":"value:,
"gender":"value"
}

userId=123456

How to make angular httpClient PUT request in angular 4 and above

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `HttpClient` to do that from a service class.
Create a service and Inject HttpClient to your service.
and then in the `putRequestHttp` method where you are making http call:

```
    putRequestHttp(userObj): any {
    //optional url query params for request
    const params = new HttpParams()
                    .set('param1', param1Value)
                    .set('param2', param2Value);

    return this.httpClient.put(`my-url-http`, userObj, { params } )

   }
```

You need to subscribe to `putRequestHttp` method of service from your component. pass the user object to it and your request will go fine.

Check the [official tutorial guide here.](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#update-heroes)

Comment: Can you explain same with my above question?

Comment: updated the answer, create a service and use the code in a service method, pass the `user` data to your service method from component at the time of subscribing it.

Comment: check the official tutorial here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#update-heroes

Answer (score 1):

Same as above but adding a little more typing / different syntactical option.  I just find this easier to read / cleaner. Assuming User is a defined type and the return type of the route is the updated user also:

```
putUser = (user: User): Observable<User> => {
    return this.httpClient.put<User>('api route', user);
}
```